# Couldn't find tsconfig.json. tsconfig-paths will be skipped

Tags: typescript, continuous-integration, cypress, cicd, tsconfig

in the step in my workflow which is end to end test using cypress supposed to run , i have encountered to this error :

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:34671/devtools/browser/226bd343-4fb3-458e-a94b-d0ea5d4c7bbb
> [2199:0108/201621.218902:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(590)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: unknown error type:
> Couldn't find tsconfig.json. tsconfig-paths will be skipped

i have no typescript in the repository, the issue is somehow related to cypress i even found this on github :
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25335

and tried to solve the problem with updating the tsconfig-paths but issue still persists.
cypress tests are passed locally. i have almost no experience working with CI/CD and i am learning actually.